# Unexpected Reloading in SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

`

```
`struct ANINewsView: SwiftUI.View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: TownhallHomeCoordinator
    @StateObject var viewModel: ANIViewModel = ANIViewModel(aniService: ANIServiceManager())
    @State private var lastItemMaxY: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var contentHeight: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some SwiftUI.View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                if viewModel.isLoading {
                    EmptyView()
                } else {
                    if viewModel.errorMessage.isEmpty {
                        VStack {
                            if !viewModel.aniBannerData.isEmpty {
                                CustomSectionHeader(title: AppString.breakingNewsString)
                                ANINewsBannerView(bannerData: viewModel.aniBannerData)
                                    .frame(height: 220)
                                    .environmentObject(coordinator)
                            } else {
                                Color.clear
                                    .frame(height: 220)
                            }
                            
                            if !viewModel.aniListData.isEmpty {
                                CustomSectionHeader(title: AppString.forYouString)
                                ANINewsListView(viewModel: viewModel)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 7)
                                    .environmentObject(coordinator)
                            } else {
                                Color.clear
                            }
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
                
                if viewModel.loadMore {
                    ProgressView()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                coordinator.showNavigationBar()
            }
            .task({
                refreshData()
            })
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.errorMessage) { newErrorMessage in
            if !newErrorMessage.isEmpty {
                coordinator.showToast(message: newErrorMessage)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: coordinator.refreshNewTab) { refresh in
            if refresh {
                refreshData()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.isLoading) { refresh in
            if !refresh {
                self.coordinator.hideLoader()
                self.coordinator.refreshNewTab = refresh
            } else {
                self.coordinator.showLoader()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func refreshData() {
        self.viewModel.errorMessage = ""
        self.viewModel.isLoading = true
        self.viewModel.aniBannerData = []
        self.viewModel.aniListData = []
        self.viewModel.aniNewsData = nil
        Task {
            coordinator.showLoader()
            await self.viewModel.fetchAniData()
        }
    }
}

struct ANINewsListView: SwiftUI.View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: TownhallHomeCoordinator
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ANIViewModel
    
    var body: some SwiftUI.View {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(viewModel.aniListData, id: \.self) { post in
                HStack {
                    if let urls = post.urls,
                       let other = urls.other,
                       let firstElement = other.first {
                        LinkPreviewerImage(imageUrlString: firstElement.completeURL)
                            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                            .cornerRadius(10.0)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                coordinator.openLinkInBrowser(urlString: post.urls?.other?.first?.completeURL)
                            }
                    } else {
                        Color.clear
                            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                            .cornerRadius(10.0)
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                        HStack(content: {
                            Group(content: {
                                CustomHeaderAsyncImage(urlString: Domain.getUserBoardinURL()+URLStruct.userProfilePhoto+"/\(post.username ?? "")/medium/")
                                    .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                                    .cornerRadius(13.0)
                                
                                Text("@\(post.username ?? "")")
                                    .font(.WorkSans(.regular, size: 12))
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                            })
                            .onTapGesture {
                                coordinator.navigateToProfileVC(userName: post.username)
                            }
                            
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 4, height: 4)
                    
                            Text(post.formattedPostCreatedAt ?? "")
                                .font(.WorkSans(.regular, size: 10))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .truncationMode(.tail)
                    
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Menu {
                                Button(action: {
                                    coordinator.shareAniPost(id: post.postID ?? "")
                                }, label: {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(.shareSVG)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .renderingMode(.template)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            .frame(width: 13, height: 13)
                                        Text(AppString.shareString)
                                            .font(.WorkSans(.regular, size: 14))
                                    }
                                })
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 30)
                        })
                        BannerViewDescription(text: (post.text ?? ""), numberOfLines: 3)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                coordinator.openDetails(id: post.postID)
                            }
                        
                        HStack(content: {
                            HStack(content: {
                                Button(action: {
                                    coordinator.openCommentView(post: post)
                                }, label: {
                                    Image((post.commentSelf ?? 0 == 1) ? .replied : .snippetComment)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                })
                                Text("\(post.comment ?? 0)")
                                    .font(.WorkSans(.regular, size: 14))
                            })
                            .padding(.trailing, 20)
                            
                            HStack(content: {
                                Button(action: {
                                    guard GlobalVariables.sharedManager.isRegisteredUser else {
                                        coordinator.showLoginPop()
                                        return
                                    }
                                    Task {
                                        await viewModel.performLikeDislikeAction(with: post)
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Image((post.likeSelf ?? 0 == 1) ? .liked :  .postLikeIcon)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                })
                                Text("\(post.like ?? 0)")
                                    .font(.WorkSans(.regular, size: 14))
                            })
                        })
                        
                    })
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .frame(height: 130)
                .id(post.id)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    if post.postID == viewModel.aniNewsData?.data?.oldPost?.last?.postID {
                        Task {
                            await viewModel.loadMoreData()
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
final class ANIViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let aniServiceManager: ANIServiceProtocol
    
    var aniNewsData: TownHallData?
    @Published var aniBannerData: [TownHallPost] = []
    @Published var aniListData: [TownHallPost] = []
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    @Published var errorMessage: String = ""
    @Published var loadMore: Bool = false
    
    init(aniService: ANIServiceProtocol) {
        self.aniServiceManager = aniService
    }
    
    func fetchAniData() async {
        var skip = 0
        var prePageId = ""
        
        if let newsDataModel = aniNewsData, let newData = newsDataModel.data?.oldPost {
            skip = newData.count
            prePageId = newData.first?.postID ?? ""
        }
        
        aniServiceManager.fetchANIData(with: skip, prePageId: prePageId)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                    case .finished:
                        break // API request completed successfully
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.isLoading = false
                        self.loadMore = false
                        self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                guard let self else { return }
                    self.handleResponse(response: response, skip: skip)
                    self.isLoading = false
                    self.loadMore = false
            }).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func handleResponse(response: TownHallData, skip: Int) {
        switch response.code {
            case APIStatus.SuccessCode :
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    if skip == 0 {
                        self.aniNewsData = response
                        self.aniBannerData = response.data?.oldPost?.prefix(10).map { $0 } ?? []
                        self.aniListData = response.data?.oldPost?.dropFirst(10).map { $0 } ?? []
                    } else {
                        if let existingOldPost = self.aniNewsData?.data?.oldPost, !existingOldPost.isEmpty {
                            if let responseOldData = response.data?.oldPost, !responseOldData.isEmpty {
                                if !responseOldData.allSatisfy({ existingOldPost.contains($0) }) {
                                    self.aniNewsData?.data?.oldPost?.append(contentsOf: ( responseOldData))
                                    self.aniListData.append(contentsOf: (response.data?.oldPost ?? []))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case APIStatus.NoInternetCode :
                errorMessage = AlertMesage.NoInterNetMsg
            case APIStatus.FailureCode :
                AppDelegate.logEventsForAnalyticsGTM(event: "event error", category: "error", action: "\(response.code)" , label: Utility.getUserId(), screenName: "TownHall", sectionName: "TownHall")
                return
            case APIStatus.TimeOutCode :
                errorMessage = AppString.timeOutString
                Analytics.logEvent("Server Timeout", parameters: ["url":  BaseURL + URLStruct.PostPaginateNew])
                return
            default:
                errorMessage = AppString.pleaseTryAgain
        }
    }
    
    func performLikeDislikeAction(with post: TownHallPost) async {
        
        guard let id = post.postID else { return }
        let action: String = post.likeSelf == 1 ? ActionsType.dislike.rawValue : ActionsType.like.rawValue
        
        aniServiceManager.likeDislikePost(action: action, postId: id)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                    case .finished:
                        break // API request completed successfully
                    case .failure(let error):
                        AppLog.viewCycleErrorLog(error)
                        break
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                guard let self else { return }
                
                var updatedPost = post
                
                updatedPost.likeSelf = response.data.selfLikes
                updatedPost.like = response.data.likes
                updatedPost.dislike = response.data.dislikes
                updatedPost.dislikeSelf = response.data.selfDislikes
                if let index = self.aniNewsData?.data?.oldPost?.firstIndex(where: { $0.postID == id }) {
                    self.aniNewsData?.data?.oldPost?[index] = updatedPost
                }
                
                if let index = self.aniListData.firstIndex(where: { $0.postID == id }) {
                    self.aniListData[index].likeSelf = response.data.selfLikes
                    self.aniListData[index].like = response.data.likes
                    self.aniListData[index].dislike = response.data.dislikes
                    self.aniListData[index].dislikeSelf = response.data.selfDislikes
                }
            }).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func loadMoreData() async {
        guard !self.loadMore else { return }
        self.loadMore = true
        Task {
            await self.fetchAniData()
        }
    }
}``
```

on loadMoreData and performLikeDislikeAction complete ANINewsListView is reloading instead of only loading for new element

on loadMoreData
only load new elements and loading should be done for new elements only rather than for existing elements
and performLikeDislikeAction
only like count and image of particular element should change instead of reloading complete ANIListView

Comment: In SwiftUI you need to use View structs, a view model object won't work.

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I would like to be honest. Obviously, you got overwhelmed by the not so accidental complexity of this code. Sadly, I'm seeing this a lot. Please note, that there are more issues than the one you noticed, and probably more than I discovered glancing over the code. I would strongly recommend rethinking the design, striving for clarity.

Comment: Sample project Link: https://github.com/LakhinaRajat/HostingViewIssue

Comment: @MatBuompy Can you please help me fix the issue I have also provided the sample project